# i got this error when i deploy my App : You must supply a layout_width attribute

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

i'm going to build a search tab to my App, My layout code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout >
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
</LinearLayout>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/etSearch"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
android:hint="Search Friends"
android:textColor="#0000"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

my Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout >
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
 </LinearLayout>
 <EditText
 android:id="@+id/etSearch"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
 android:hint="Search Friends"
 android:textColor="#0000"/>
 </FrameLayout>
```

when i deploy my app i got this error:
    You must supply a layout_width attribute
can any one help me???

Comment: please post the full stack trace. btw an empty linearlayout is useless, you can remove it since it has no ID.  One of your xml object must have no `layout_width`. Try searching in others files and post please the stack

Comment: the problem solved when i delet an empty linearlayout :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have `LinearLayout` which is `match_parent` and there will be no space for your `EditText`